# Is there a possible way to break a dataloader loop?

Tags: gpu, pytorch

I use a PyTorch DataLoader in my code, and there is loop using data from this dataloader.
However, when I try to end this loop, it failed.
There is no error info. The program is still.
GPU is not out of memory, but the volatile GPU-util keeps to be 0%

```py
def function():
    seq_dt = SequenceLoader(image_list)
    seq_loader = DataLoader(seq_dt, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, sampler=None, 
    num_workers=1, pin_memory=True)
    for image_idx, img in enumerate(seq_loader):
        ...
        ...
        my_variable = ...
        ...
        if my_variable<my_threshold:
            return my_flag
```

Could you please help me with this problem?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: What is `SequenceLoader`?

Comment: Have you tried `num_workers=0`?

Comment: @Shai, thanks! I tried num_workers=0 and it works. Could you please explain the reason briefly? Because num_workers=0 may lower the speed

Comment: I suspect `SequenceLoader` is a data *loader* rather than a *Dataset*, thus leading to clashes between spawned sub-processes of the two loaders.

Comment: @Shai, thanks for your kindness. I have proposed a detailed post here. FYI [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55841546/problems-when-i-use-two-dataloaders-to-read-the-same-dataset-simultaneously)